# Calculating a limit power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A = [ [ 4 , -2, 3] , [$\frac{1}{2}$ , 0 , $\frac{1}{2}$] , [-4,$\frac{5}{2}$,-3] ]

Suppose, we know the eigenvalues $\frac{1}{2}$,$-\frac{1}{2}$ and 1 of A and a matrix T with
$T^{-1}AT = D$, where D is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues as its entries.
$T^{-1}$ was also calculated in the exercise.

How can we calculate $lim_{n->\infty}A^n$ from this ?

I tried to use that $A^n$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^n$, if A has eigenvalue $\lambda$, 
but could not make progress.

Comment: Note that $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(A^n=\left(TDT^{-1}\right)^n=TD^nT^{-1}\right).$

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward. Some people will accept the following as a proof, though:
$$\begin{align} \left(TDT^{-1}\right)^n&=\left(TDT^{-1}\right)\left(TDT^{-1}\right)\ldots \left(TDT^{-1}\right)\\ &=TD\left(T^{-1}T\right)D\left(T^{-1}T\right)\ldots \left(T^{-1}T\right)DT^{-1}\\ &=TDIDI\ldots IDT^{-1}\\ &=TD^nT^{-1}.\end{align}$$

Comment: I noticed this soon after my comment. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have
$$A^n=T D^nT^{-1},$$
and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}D^n=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$, the limiting expression for $A^n$ will be
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^n=T \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)T^{-1}.$$
Even more specifically,
$$\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^n\right)_{jk}=T_{j3}(T^{-1})_{3k}.$$

Comment: If you type \$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\$ it will render as $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$, if you care...

Comment: A lot easier than I thought. Thank you!